# Kubernetes - nginx ingress using regex

Tags: regex, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

my Kubernetes has a deployment what contains:

- a Keycloak, with an httpRelativePath: `"/auth/"`
- a Spring based backend
- a React based frontend

and I need to expose all of them. Currently, I am focusing on the Ingress Controller. For this, I have enabled the `use-regex` and `rewrite-target` annotations set.

The first path, for the backend, work fine and I get the wanted response from the backend application.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: abc-ingress
  namespace: abc
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /be(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /fe(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

The problem appears when I want to set a path for the Keycloak:

```
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: keycloak-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

What I want is to set the ingress controller to route me to the /auth/ but not to /be/ or /fe/. I could set something like

```
 - path: /keycloak/(/|$)(.*)
```

but then the `httpRelativePath` (used for by Keycloak to generate further links inside of it) doesn't match anymore.

How can I exclude the `be` and `fe` from the keycloak's path in the first regex groupping without to harm the `rewrite-target: /$2` ?

Answer (score 0):

we use separate Ingress resources for each service (backend, frontend, and Keycloak). This configuration ensures that each service is isolated and does not interfere with the routing of the others. Here's how it works:

1. **Backend and Frontend Ingress Resources:**

   - Requests to paths starting with `/be/` are routed to the backend service.
   - Requests to paths starting with `/fe/` are routed to the frontend service.
   - The `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` annotation is applied to these Ingress resources, which means that any part of the path matched by `(.*)` (represented by `$2`) is rewritten as the new path. This is commonly used to remove the `/be/` and `/fe/` prefixes when forwarding requests to the respective services. This rewrite does not affect Keycloak.
2. **Keycloak Ingress Resource:**

   - Requests to paths starting with `/auth/` are routed to the Keycloak service.
   - The `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /auth/` annotation is applied to this Ingress resource. This means that the path is rewritten to `/auth/`, which preserves Keycloak's `httpRelativePath`.

The key difference in this configuration is that the rewrite annotation is not applied to the Keycloak Ingress resource. This ensures that requests to Keycloak's `/auth/` path and its subpaths are routed to Keycloak without modification, preserving its `httpRelativePath`. Meanwhile, the requests to `/be/` and `/fe/` are correctly rewritten before reaching their respective services.

This configuration allows you to achieve the desired routing behavior without interfering with Keycloak's internal path handling.